# sending mail with attachment AND a message

Tags: java, email, gmail, email-attachments

why does it not work to send a message and an attachment
when i use this code below it will send the mail and attachment but not the message.
some one who knows why or how to ?

Working code, I have used Java Mail 1.4.7 jar.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.mail.*;

public class MailProjectClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String username = "your.mail.id@gmail.com";
    final String password = "your.password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from.mail.id@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to.mail.id@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("PFA");

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String file = "path of file to be attached";
        String fileName = "attachmentName";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        System.out.println("Sending");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception ? if yes post it.

Comment: no i dont get any exception, it walks true the code normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add email body as a separate multi part

```
String body="Email body template";
MimeBodyPart mailBody = new MimeBodyPart();
mailBody.setText(body);
multipart.addBodyPart(mailBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that you missed the `;` here `String fileName = "attachmentName"` as typo.

But other than that your code works perfectly fine.

Comment: thanks for that change it edit the text because of personal information and forgot that ;

Comment: what is the file format and size of your attachment?

Comment: .TXT file size: 363bytes but it can be bigger if im gonna use it